# Calculate column based on total column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am working with SSRS 2008, I created a matrix with the following data

```
           2014           2015
hp          15             12
dell        14             13 
Total       29             25
```

I need to get the value of Total divided by the value of data  the result matrix should be like this:

```
           2014     T          2015   T
hp          15     1.93        12    2.08
dell        14     2.07        13    1.92
Total       29      4          25    4
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you calculating the total columns for each year?

Comment: i added a totals for a row group with ssrs

Comment: What I mean is how are you calculating the `1.93` and `2.07` etc.?

Comment: Total divided by the value of data for example `29/15` `29/14`

Comment: Are you looking for the percentage as that would be calculated the other way round `15/29`?

Comment: exactly but the problem is how can i get the value of the Total

Answer (score 2):

To reference a textbox within a table / matrix in SSRS, build an expression that references it for example:

```
=ReportItems!Result.Value / ReportItems!Total.Value
```

Where `Result` is the name of the textbox row and `Total` is the name of the column total textbox.

Note that this will throw an error if trying to divide by `0`. Here's a handy piece of code that you can use to handle any divide by 0 errors:

```
Public Function Divider (ByVal Dividend As Double, ByVal Divisor As Double)
    If IsNothing(Divisor) Or Divisor = 0
        Return 0
    Else
        Return Dividend/Divisor
    End If
End Function
```

*(Not my code, unfortunately cannot remember the author to credit)*

To use the code, right-click on the report and goto `Report Properties`. Then on the left hand menu click code. Once there, paste the code in.

Then to use the code, build an expression like so:

```
=Code!Divider(ReportItems!Result.Value, ReportItems!Total.Value)
```